# UITextField input string updating

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I have a textfield that I want to input in it with numpad keyboard.
I want the textfield to be like 00.00 at first, and as the user strat typing it update from left to right, or right to left. e.g if he types 2 followed by 3 then textfield should be like 23.00, and also the user just allowed to input a number with at most 2 digits after decimal point.
How can I get this functionallity??

Thanks in Advanced.

Cheers,
Siavash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `.h`

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) int maximumFractionDigits;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* decimalSeparator;
```

In `loadView` or `viewDidLoad` put this,

```
NSNumberFormatter* numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[numberFormatter setCurrencyCode:@"GBP"];
self.maximumFractionDigits = numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits;
self.decimalSeparator = numberFormatter.decimalSeparator;
[numberFormatter release];
```

In `UITextFieldDelegate` method

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField*)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString*)string {
// get current cursor position
UITextRange* selectedRange = [textField selectedTextRange];
UITextPosition* start = textField.beginningOfDocument;
NSInteger cursorOffset = [textField offsetFromPosition:start toPosition:selectedRange.start];
// Update the string in the text input
NSMutableString* currentString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:textField.text];
NSUInteger currentLength = currentString.length;
[currentString replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
// Strip out the decimal separator
[currentString replaceOccurrencesOfString:self.decimalSeparator withString:@"" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [currentString length])];
// Generate a new string for the text input
int currentValue = [currentString intValue];
NSString* format = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%.%df", self.maximumFractionDigits];
double minorUnitsPerMajor = pow(10, self.maximumFractionDigits);
NSString* newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:format, currentValue / minorUnitsPerMajor];
textField.text = newString;
// if the cursor was not at the end of the string being entered, restore cursor position
if (cursorOffset != currentLength) {
    int lengthDelta = newString.length - currentLength;
    int newCursorOffset = MAX(0, MIN(newString.length, cursorOffset + lengthDelta));
    UITextPosition* newPosition = [textField positionFromPosition:textField.beginningOfDocument offset:newCursorOffset];
    UITextRange* newRange = [textField textRangeFromPosition:newPosition toPosition:newPosition];
    [textField setSelectedTextRange:newRange];
}

return NO;
```

}

Comment: That's work just fine, but one more thing, How the user can input the decimal point on a numpad keyboard with a DONE button?
I saw programs that have a text field with 00.00, and as you start inserting numbers it first populates two digits after the decimal and then goes on.
I mean sth like that

Comment: use `textField.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;` for decimal keyboard. But for done button you have to customise the keyboard or you can use toolbar with done button..

Comment: I know that, I have customize my keyboard and it has that done button.
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/discount-calculator-free-shopping/id473404571?mt=8
I want sth like this.

Comment: Did you see the app? Without inserting a decimal point you get a floating point number, you insert 2345, then you get 45.23!!!
I want this.

Comment: if you enter 23456 it should show 234.56 right??? or the user entry would be only four digits (1234)???

Comment: but how I can implement this function??

Comment: The keyboard doesn't work
actually nothing insert in textfield as I push the buttons

Comment: the macro MAX_LENGTH: you initialize it with what?

Comment: I dont get the viewDidLoad stuff you put in??
Why currency format ??

Comment: I made a whole new project, single view with one textfield. and still the keyboard does not update the textfield

Comment: i just put this for getting `decimalSeparator` you can use `NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle` also....

Comment: you have to set the textfield.delegate=self;

Comment: Dont act smart ok...?? even though it is not working its your fault... you have to study the `UITextField` basics.....\

Comment: I know. The delegate is set, when I comment out your code, its work. It means delegate is set correctly, it think though.

Comment: thanks for your time. I didn't act smart, it's just not working for me...
And I know the basics of UITextField. I have Two calculator program on app store, so at least I know the basics.

Comment: See what if you can tell me what I'm doing wrong
I create a single view project, drag out a textfield into my view. connect the outlet and delegate by ctr+dragging. add UITextFieldDelegate to my header. copy and paste all of your code. 
And when I touch the textfield keyboard slide up, but when I try to inputting, nothing appears on textfield.
So what you think I'm missing here?

Comment: @MountianLion, Ive just copy and paste your code, boom!!! it works. That if statement...
Your awesome man. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below delegate method. Change as your requirements.

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
NSString *replacedSting = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

NSArray *noOfDigits = [replacedSting componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
if([noOfDigits count]>=2)
{
    NSString *sepStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[noOfDigits objectAtIndex:1]];
    return !([sepStr length]>1);
}
return YES;
}
```

Comment: @Ramu Yes, what about [sep objectAtIndex:1], where and how should I declare "sep"??

Comment: @siavashAlipour, try now and let me know.. In my project I tried with only one decimal point..If u don't get it, I will try here and let u know

Comment: @RamuPasupuleti, I think I didn't make myself clear in question well, what I'm looking for is sth like this:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/discount-calculator-free-shopping/id473404571?mt=8
I want sth like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to set the tens digit BEFORE the ones digit, this is a bit of a hack but I think it could work. You could use something like the UITextField's delegate method

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

Make sure you set the text field's delegate, and then use this method. You could keep a counter yourself to figure out which index to change upon every keystroke. You would ignore the range and change it out yourself with the one you're keeping track of. For instance, start at index 0 and increment it every time the method is called, but after X seconds of no button being pressed, reset to the first index.

Otherwise, Ramu's answer should work for you!